# Load Multiple SQL Dumps as Once

Tags: mysql

I have a folder with full of dump files as dumpA.sql, dumpB.sql, etc.

I use mysql command to run each dump individually. I'm planning to whole collection at once.

I'm using Windows.

**Here is what i do:**

```
C:\> cd c:\xampp\mysql\bin

C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1;
```

**Once i login, i do the following:**

```
mysql> use databaseName;
mysql> source folder/dumpA.sql;
```

**I repeat this process for each file:**

```
mysql> source folder/dumpB.sql;
```

Time consumig...

**Is there a way to run all dumps within the folder at once?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FOR %s IN (*.sql) DO mysql -u root -h0 databaseName < %s
```

on the batch file you will need to use %%s instead of %s

enjoy :)